# need help installing java 8 on ubuntu server

Tags: software-installation, java

I cannot figure out anywhere online how to download java 8 just to host a minecraft server and since there is no more sudo apt install javajdk-8-jdk i cant figure it out

Comment: The package name is `openjdk-8-jre` (you don't need the JDK unless you're compiling something - just use the JRE). That should work for older versions of Minecraft, like 1.8. However, newer versions of Minecraft (1.16+) require Java 16 (`openjdk-16-jre`), and Minecraft 1.18 uses Java 17 (`openjdk-17-jre`).

Comment: https://prnt.sc/3LcPxjj6Df6e

Comment: also i am running a 1.12.2 server so i would prefer

Comment: Please provide OS, product & release details.. I see `openjdk-8-jre` available for Ubuntu Server products; for most it's in `universe` but you've not provided any product/release details.  Are you using a Ubuntu Core Server? a standard Ubuntu Server install? and what release of your *unstated* product?  (*and if you're using a release that required 'universe', have you enabled it? we don't know what you're running so cannot know if that applies to you as we're limited to details you provide*)

Comment: OS is a standard install of ubuntu server 20.04

Comment: The device im using is an dell poweredge 2850

Comment: Release details or additional details should be in your question; do you have `universe` enabled?  The package is there - `openjdk-8-jre | 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04   | focal-updates/universe   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x`  for most architectures too !

Comment: I am new to linux and i am not sure how to enable universe

Answer (score 0):

As you're on Ubuntu Server, first enable the universe repository to get Java.

Run this command on your Ubuntu server:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then refresh your repositories so you can install Java:

```
sudo apt update
```

Finally, install Java 8, as you want to run a Minecraft 1.12 server:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

If you want to run a Minecraft 1.16/1.17 server, install `openjdk-16-jre` instead.

For Minecraft 1.18, install `openjdk-17-jre`.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Thank you so much for this

Comment: You're welcome.